# API to check battery saver mode in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to check if battery saver mode is on, so that I can reduce intensive operations ( such as increase poll interval, reduce graphics, turn off geocordinatewatcher)

Comment: It must be possible somehow. The Nokia diagnostic tool shows the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this information is not possible with the publically available SDK for 3rd Party apps. Hence its not possible to detect if a phone is running in battery saver mode.

Answer (score 1):

There's no WP7 API to check battery status.

That functionality was part of a new API was introduced in WP8. You can use the new Windows.Phone.Devices.Power namespace to get battery info.

```
    using Windows.Phone.Devices.Power;

    private void OS_Batery(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var battery = Battery.GetDefault();

        if (battery != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(battery.RemainingChargePercent);
            Debug.WriteLine(battery.RemainingDischargeTime);

            battery.RemainingChargePercentChanged +=
                (s, args) => Debug.WriteLine(battery.RemainingChargePercent);
        }
    }
```